# Passing array as argument in Parameterized Constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I am trying to overload the >> operator to rotate the elements in the array.I have removed the array declaration and initialization for shorten the code.
But compiler is giving error as "invalid use of undefined type 'class ABC'." and many more.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class ABC
{
      int iarr[10],n2,n3;
      char carr[10];

      Public:
             ABC();
      ABC(int arr[],char car[],int n,int n1)
      {
              n2=n; n3=n1;
              for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
              iarr[i]=arr[i];
              for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
                      carr[i]=car[i];
      }

      ABC operator>>(int n)
      {
          while(n)
          {
                  int temp;
                  temp=iarr[n2-1];
                  for(int i=n2-1;i>=0;i--)
                  {
                      iarr[i]=iarr[i-1];
                  }
                  iarr[0]=temp;
          }
      }

      void display()
      {
          for(int i=0;i<n2;i++)
              printf("%d\t",iarr[i]);
          printf("\n");
          for(int i=0;i<n3;i++)
              printf("%d\t",carr[i]);
      }
};

main()
{
    ABC A;
    A=ABC(arr,car,n,n1);
    A.display();
}
```

Comment: The proper way to construct an element using a non-default ctor is `ABC A(arr, carr, n, n1);` If you write `ABC A; A = ABC(...);` you'll need a default ctor and an assignment operator.

Comment: You're not modifying `n` inside `operator>>`, so this loop `while(n)` will either not run at all or run infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Your error "**invalid use of undefined type 'class ABC'**" is because of your default constructor. You have declared a default constructor, but you have not defined it.

Instead of `ABC();` you need to atleast do `ABC() {}`

Comment: After wasting about 45 mins...phew!!.'P' should not be capital in 'Public'. But compiler wasn't giving any error for this. Remaining code is correct except 'n--' in while loop.